# Can I run rails 4 project using rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to upgrade my local gem to rails 5 to create a new rails 5 application. However I have some old rails 4 applications that I don't really want to spend time in upgrading them to rails 5.

will I be able to run these projects if I upgrade to rails 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I tried it and found out that it works just fine